# How to correct image flip caused by rotating device in landscapeLeft mode

Tags: objective-c, trigonometry

Probably I missed my math class in school but can't figure out this.

I'm reading data from accelerometer and rotating image regarding data from accelerometer . Everything is working with LandscapeRight, but In landscapeLeft my imageView is flipped upside down. How can I correct this?

Simplified code bellow:

```
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration
{

    double accelerationX = acceleration.x;
    double accelerationY = -acceleration.y;
    double currentRawReading = atan2(accelerationY, accelerationX);
    [self.sw1 setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((CGFloat) -currentRawReading)];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CGAffineTransformMakeRotation` expects radians, so if you add or subtract `M_PI` from `currentRawReading` your `sw1` should rotate 180° more.